# Error when open MATLAB R2016a

Tags: matlab

I have installed MATLAB R2016a on my Ubuntu 14.04. Each time I open MATLAB, the error comes out. However, MATLAB can still work.
So, how can I fix the error?

---

[image: Error in Command Window]

Comment: It may be worth contacting Mathworks Customer Support.

Comment: It seems to be graphics card drivers issue.

Comment: This is a bug with Ubuntu 14.04 and MATLAB R2016a specifically.  The workaround is to use software rendering under OpenGL (see answer below).  This bug goes away when you upgrade to R2016b or if you use a different version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by launching MATLAB like so:

```
matlab -softwareopengl
```

Comment: @KeGong If the answer completely solved your needs, consider marking it as accepted (tick mark on the upper left corner of this post)